# StreamWriter class behavior when call from .net core 2.1 vs .net core 3.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard, .net-core-3.0, .net-core-2.1

I have written a dll in .net standard 2.0. Suppose which just write data in text file through `StreamWriter`.

**Note:** I know below code could be write in more better way. This code is only test base.

Dll code :

```
public class WriteIntoLog
    {
        private StreamWriter _streamWriter;
        public void WriteMsgToFile(string message)
        {
            try
            {
                bool close = true;

                if (_streamWriter == null || _streamWriter.BaseStream == null)
                    _streamWriter = new StreamWriter("Test.txt", true);

                _streamWriter.WriteLine(message);

                if (close)
                    CloseLogFileStream(false);
            }
            catch (IOException ioEx)
            {
                throw new Exception(ioEx.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }              
        }
        public void CloseLogFileStream(bool dispose)
        {
            if (_streamWriter != null)
            {
                _streamWriter.Close();
                if (dispose)
                    _streamWriter = null;
            }

        }
    }
```

And calling this dll from console app written in `.net core 2.1`

```
class TStreamWriter
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WriteIntoLog log = new WriteIntoLog();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                log.WriteMsgToFile($"Loop no: {i.ToString()}");
            }
                        
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
```

Now this code running as expected but when I change target platform of console app to `.net core 3.0` the code return exception that "Cannot write to a closed TextWriter.".

So why it is not return an exception while running console app in `.net core 2.1`.

Comment: There's no difference. The `WriteIntoLog` is buggy though, and will use the same *cached* stream whether it's alive or not. Given that this stream isn't needed outside `WriteMsgToFile`, there's no reason to store it in a field

Comment: Why write your own logging code though, instead of using a library like Serilog or .NET Core's own Microsoft.Extensions.Logging ?

Comment: BTW you could replace all this code with `File.AppendAllText(somePath,message + "\n");`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos there is some difference because the same code run well in 2.1 while give exception in 3.0.

Comment: Not really - the instance is disposed, dead, not meant to be used again. In fact, I'm surprised you aren't getting an `ObjectDisposedException` when you try to access `BaseStream`.

Comment: In fact, your `Dispose()` code ensures you'll always have a bad object. `StreamWriter.Dispose()` just calls `Close()`. Even though you have a dead object, you don't set the field to null but try to touch it again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating an instance of `WriteIntoLog` and then calling functions on it multiple times. After the first time, since `bool close` is always `true`, `Close()` is called on the stream. The future loop iterations (2 - 10) try to write using a closed stream, since `_streamWriter` is closed and this code will no longer evaluate to true:

```
if (_streamWriter == null || _streamWriter.BaseStream == null)
                _streamWriter = new StreamWriter("Test.txt", true);
```

Comment: All true, but it does not explain the difference between the two target frameworks.

Comment: @Maarten haven't looked into it, but I'd pretty much guarantee that `_streamWriter.BaseStream` is null in core 2.1 once the stream is closed, and not null in 3.0

Comment: Good guess, that is indeed what happens.

Comment: @Haney you are right. `_streamWriter.BaseStream` is not null in 3.0. It mean that there are difference in implementation of `StreamWriter` class in both the versions

Comment: @vikky why write such code at all? It's a disposed class, there's absolutely no guarantee that its members like BaseStream would be in one state or another.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think you did not read "Note" part of the question. I know I can use "Using"  to dispose object automatically.

Comment: I did. The code is buggy, depending on undocumented behaviour of a dead object. It's *guaranteed* it's going to break one way or another

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an issue because `_streamWriter` is closed, but it is not `null`.

You can simply do this.

```
using (StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(""))
{
...//Add your code here
}
```

Comment: It does not explain the difference between the two target frameworks.

Comment: @Maarten there's no difference in the *frameworks*. The OP uses buggy code *and* tries to touch implementation details through the BaseStream though. There's no guarantee that the stream of a *disposed* writer would be in one state or another

Comment: @Maarten I agree, but this is happening to the bug in the code. So if we solve the issue, he won't face any such error.